# Nettiers WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, .nettiers

Can We use Nettiers in WPF?
or does codesmith have any template for code generation for WPF and MVVM design pattern?
i was using NetTiers And CodeSmith For Windows And Asp.net APplications.
Does it available on WPF applications?
please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't come across anyone off the top of my head who has used .netTiers with WPF. But that doesn't mean that it's not possible. CodeSmith doesn't have any templates for WPF and MVVM design patterns. If you have have a pattern I would be more than happy to work with you on making that into a template. Please contact CodeSmith Support for more information.

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski